# Pick out the convergent series:

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, cauchy-sequences

> Let $X$ be a metric space and let $f : X → \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function.
>   Pick out the true statements.
>
> (a) $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy sequences.
>
> (b) If $X$ is compact, then $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy
>   sequences.
>
> (c) If $X = \mathbb{R^n}$, then $f$ always maps Cauchy sequences into Cauchy
>   sequences.

(a) Let  $\epsilon>0$ given, $\exists \delta>0$: $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ such that $\forall x : d(x,y)<\delta$ ($\because$ $f$ is continuous).
consider {$x_n$} be a cauchy sequence. For the above $\delta$ , $\exists N(\delta)$ : $d(x_n,x_m)<\delta$ $\forall m,n \ge N(\delta)$.

> It is given in the answer key that (a) is false, proving some thing
>   is true is easy compared to proving something is false. How to cook a
>   counter example from the given data?

(b) Given that $X$ is compact $\implies$ $X$ is sequentially Compact($\because$ $X$ is a metric space). Suppose {$x_n$} be a cauchy sequence , $\exists$ a convergent subsequence converging in $X$.

> How to proceed further?

(c) I hope (c) can be done with the help of(a).

Please help me. I am facing difficulty in cooking counter examples? in this region. How to learn making counter examples.

Comment: For (a), consider $X = (0,1)$ (with the usual metric) and $f(x) = 1/x$. What does $f$ do with a sequence $x_n$ that approaches zero?

Comment: @Bungo How did you get the counter example? Can you suggest some method to find counter examples faster?

Comment: Well, you know that if $X$ is complete, then all Cauchy sequences converge, so any continuous $f$ will map such a sequence to another convergent sequence (hence Cauchy). So you need a non-complete metric space for a counterexample. A natural example of such a space is an open interval.

Comment: As far as $c)$ is concerned i think $c$ is true. Note $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is complete so $(x_{n})$ cauchy is same as saying $(x_n)$ is convergent. So assume $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_{n}=x$. Since $f$ is continuous you have $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} f(x_n)=f(x)$. You want to esitmate $|f(x_n)-f(x_m)|$, for this think as to how you can make both $|f(x_n)-f(x)|$ and $|f(x_m)-f(x)|$ smaller

Comment: Thank you @Bungo and S.C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) is correct because continuous function on compact set in metric space is uniformly continuous, this can be done by Lebesgue number of the sequentially compact set (sequentially compact = compact in metric space).

Or we can argue with the following fashion. Since $X$ is sequentially compact, given Cauchy sequence $(x_{n})$, it contains a convergent subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})$, say, $x_{n_{k}}\rightarrow x$, so $x_{n}\rightarrow x$ by Cauchy property. So $f(x_{n})\rightarrow f(x)$ by continuity.

Comment: Can't we prove using just definition?